# Fit and Data in (1/x,-Log[y])-Scale

Tags: plotting, fitting, nonlinear, logarithmic-scale

I have data as a list of xy-pairs, but have to plot it in `{1/(x), -Log[y]}` space. I am also making a fit to the data, so I used the raw data for my fit and I used `Plot[-Log[nml[1/x], ...]` for my plot.

```
data = 
  {{321.5, 5740.15}, {331.4, 0.00226439}, {341.3, 0.0000574524}, 
   {351.2, 6.98218*10^-6}, {361.2, 1.59491*10^-6}}

Plotdata = Transpose[{1/data[[All,1]],-Log[data[[All,2]]]]

(*k=constant*)
k = 8*10^-5 
model = d Exp[e/(k x)]
nml = NonlinearModelFit[FitListetMax, model, {e, d}, x];
Fittarr["ParameterTable"];

Show[ListPlot[Plotdata], Plot[-Log[nml[1/T]], {T, 0.001, 0.0035}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]

The plot of the fit isn't good in `{1/x, -Log[y]` space. I checked the normal plot of the fit with the data and the fit is good, so it has to be a problem with the way I'm plotting the fit or the data in `{1/x, -Log[y]` space.

Any ideas?

---

Sry! I forgot to rename, of course it is:

```
data={{321.5, 5740.15}, {331.4, 0.00226439}, {341.3, 0.0000574524}, {351.2,
   6.98218*10^-6}, {361.2, 1.59491*10^-6}}

Plotdata=Transpose[{1/data[[All,1]],-Log[data[[All,2]]}]

(*k=constant*)
k=8*10^-5 

model=d Exp[e/(k x)]
nml=NonlinearModelFit[data,model,{e,d},x];
nml["ParameterTable"]; 

Show[ListPlot[Plotdata],Plot[-Log[nml[1/T]],{T,0.001,0.0035},PlotStyle->Green]]
```

And no, i dont expect a completly linear curve, but in a section around the data it should be linear.

Comment: Your code does not execute. What is `FitListetMax`?  What is `Fittarr`? And here is a brace missing:`Plotdata=Transpose[{1/data[[All,1]],-Log[data[[All,2]]]]`

Comment: Do you expect -ln(y) vs 1/x to be linear, because a close inspection of `ListPlot[Plotdata]` shows that it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
data = {{321.5, 5740.15}, {331.4, 0.00226439}, {341.3, 
     0.0000574524}, {351.2, 6.98218*10^-6}, {361.2, 
     1.59491*10^-6}} /. {x_, y_} :> {1/x, -Log[y]};
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

That's how you wanted to represent it. To fit it one needs a good model. The one you proposed is not enough for such a data.

Have fun!

Comment: Ok, thanks @AlexaiBoulbitch